# some questions about svm in R using caret package

Tags: r, svm

I need some help to understand the results from the code below:

```
library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", savePred=T)
mod <- train(Sepal.Length~., data=iris, method = "svmRadial", trControl = ctrl) 
#pred_test <-predict(mod,iris)
head(mod$pred)
mod
```

Here is the result:

```
      pred obs rowIndex    sigma    C Resample
1 4.879055 4.7       30 1.781273 0.25   Fold01
2 5.230893 4.9       38 1.781273 0.25   Fold01
3 5.268827 5.0       44 1.781273 0.25   Fold01
4 4.947738 5.0       50 1.781273 0.25   Fold01
5 6.085828 6.6       76 1.781273 0.25   Fold01
6 5.524783 5.7       80 1.781273 0.25   Fold01

Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 

150 samples
  4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 136, 135, 136, 136, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  C     RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
  0.25  0.4670729  0.7307655  0.3478073
  0.50  0.4376385  0.7559361  0.3300692
  1.00  0.4185441  0.7755009  0.3144116
```

Question1: what is `pred`?
Question2: what is `Rsquared`?

Thanks!

Comment: predicted values, [r-squared statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

Comment: Can I use cor(iris$Sepal.Length,mod$pred[1]) to test the performance of svm? Or just use Rsquared from mod?